# Subclassing UILabel to make it "tappable"

Tags: ios, uilabel, subclass

I'm subclassing `UILabel` to `FDTouchableLabel` in order to make the label behave like a link: if the user tap the label, it changes its color to the `highlightedTextColor` and **perform a selector on a target**.

The label has both a `selector` property and a `target` (weak) property, and a `addTarget:action:` method.

The problem is that when I call this (from the label itself):

```
[self.target performSelector:self.action];
```

I get (what I suppose is) an **ARC warning**: "PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown".

Is there a real problem? Would this code really leak?

(I already know about the trick to hide the warning, not interested in that. Want to understand the real *problem*.)